# Cloud function triggered by object created storage getting file not found error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a cloud function configured to be triggered on `google.storage.object.finalize` in a storage bucket. This was running well for a while. However recently I start to getting some errors `FileNotFoundError` when trying to read the file. But if I try download the file through the gsutil or the console works fine.

Code sample:

```py
def main(data, context):
    full_filename = data['name']
    bucket = data['bucket']
    df = pd.read_csv(f'gs://{bucket}/{full_filename}') # intermittent raises FileNotFoundError
```

The errors occurs most often when the file was overwritten. The bucket has the object versioning enabled.

There are something I can do?

Comment: Hi @DamiaoMartins could you please check if you are not facing an issue related to cache? As indicated in this similar case [here](https://github.com/dask/gcsfs/issues/184), it might be a cache related issue, due to the file being overwritten.

Comment: @gso_gabriel I think cloud function create a new instance every execution, so I've never think this could be a cache issue. But looks like a related issue indeed, I'll try use the `invalidate_cache` before reading the file.

Comment: Sure, I understand your point. Please, let me know if it helped you @DamiaoMartins , so I can post this as answer, in case you would consider upvoting and accepting it.

Comment: Hi @DamiaoMartins have you tried using the `invalidate_cache`?

Comment: Hi @gso_gabriel I applied the `invalidate_cache` last tuesday and since then the error didn't occurred. You can post it as answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @DamionMartins thanks for confirming it helped! I have posted as answer. Please, consider upvoting and accepting. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As clarified in this other similar case [here](https://github.com/dask/gcsfs/issues/184), sometimes cache can be an issue between Cloud Functions and Cloud Storage, where this can be causing the files to get overwritten and this way, not possible to be found, causing the `FileNotFoundError` to show up.

Using the `invalidate_cache` before reading the file can help in this situations, since it will disconsider the cache for the reading and avoid the error. The code for using `invalidate_cache` is like this:

```
import gcsfs

fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem() 
fs.invalidate_cache()
```

Comment: You can add how to use the invalidate_cache: `import gcsfs`, `fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()` and `fs.invalidate_cache()`

Answer (score 0):

Check in function logging if your function execution is not triggered twice on single object finalize:

- first triggered execution with event attribute `'size': '0'`
- second triggered execution with event attribute `size` with actual object size

If your function fails on the first you can simply filter it out by checking the attribute value and continuing only if non-zero.

```
def main(data, context):
    object_size = data['size']
    if object_size != '0':
        full_filename = data['name']
        bucket = data['bucket']
        df = pd.read_csv(f'gs://{bucket}/{full_filename}')
```

Don't know what exactly is causing the double-triggering but had similar problem once when using [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) and this was a quick solution solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've checked the logs, not seen the function was called twice per file. And in the run that raise the error the size was not zero.